# How to config the environment variable path to ensure that it opening the python from anaconda

Tags: numpy, windows-10, anaconda, environment-variables, python-3.7

I install Anconda3 on my pc (win10). And when I try to us numpy I get this Error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'".
I edit my environment variables and add this:
PYTON_HOME (C:\Users\User_name\anaconda3)
And add this also to the path.
But when I run "where python3" I still get :
"C:\Users\WIN10\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe"
how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following step:

```
In the Control Panel => System and Security => System => Edit the System Environment Variable

In the new window System Properties => Advanced => Environment Variables, set Path as "C:\Users\User_name\anaconda3"
```